# Microsoft Graph api connection

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, data-science

I am trying to get the email details from Outlook emails using Python. we got the access token, But While trying to get the email details, we are facing different issues like OrganizationGuidNotfound, and MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI.

we tried to get email details using Postman also but the same issues. Can anyone share some insights on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hi provide more information on this Question:

However, Below is a list of items to refer to

2. Mail REST API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Please note:
The API does not support accessing in-place archive mailboxes, not on Exchange Online nor on Exchange Server.

What API Version are you using? - The Outlook REST endpoints will be fully decommissioned in November 2022. Migrate existing apps to use Microsoft Graph.